# Cloud Functions Query Date from Firestore field which is a String

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a Firestore Database all fields are in String Format.

Now I need to by date on this field (reqDate) which is in string format.

Sample Data on the field (reqDate) = 10/11/2021, 9:22:11 PM

I tried the code below on Cloud Functions using moment to format the string field:

```
const thisCollection = firestore.collection("ItemList")
            .where(moment("reqDate").format('MM/DD/YYYY'), ">", "10/05/2021");
```

But it return blank or no record.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the condition you pass to you query is wrong because you need to pass:

1. The field name to filter on in the first parameter, which is now `moment("reqDate").format('MM/DD/YYYY')`, but should be `"reqDate"`.
2. The operator, which is correct in your code.
3. The value to filter on.

This date format you use is unsuitable for range filters, since strings are [ordered lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) and in that order: `"10/05/2021"` is before `"11/05/2020"`.

To allow a range query, you need a date format that allows for that. When the date is a string, the most common formats are based on [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), such as `"2021-10-17"`, because in this format dates that are after October 17 are queryable with: `.where("reqDate", ">", "2021-10-17")`